# Obfuscated Id Postgres Error in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I upgraded my app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1, but now it's unable to display individual Answers. When I go to the show page for an answer (like '/answers/0183759926'), I get an error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "--- {} "
LINE 1: ... "answers" WHERE "answers"."id" IN (1862, '--- {} 
                                                     ^
SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."id" IN (1862, '--- {} ') ORDER BY answers.updated_at DESC
```

I have a model called Answers:

```
 class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  default_scope { order('answers.updated_at DESC') }
  obfuscate_id 
  #...
```

This is the controller:

```
def show
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id]) #relies on gem
end
```

I'm using the gem 'obfuscate_id' to scramble the displayed ID:

```
 gem 'obfuscate_id', :git => 'https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id.git'
```

How do I fix the error?

Update:
This seems to be an issue with the gem's find method. See https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id/issues/19

Comment: If you find the answer yourself, you should submit it as an answer instead of updating the question.

Comment: @intgr, ok, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused by a incompatibility between the current gem and Rails 4.1. To circumvent it, I called `Answer.deobfuscate_id` to get the actual `id`, and then used `find_by(id: )` on the actual `id`.